# Load HTML Page inside CefSharp browser

Tags: c#, .net, jquery-mobile, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have an embedded chromium client named **CefSharp** in my **Windows Form Application**. On application start, I am loading a webpage in **cefsharp** from project resources using following statement in c#:

```
 web_view.LoadHtml(File.ReadAllText(@".\HelloPage.html"), @".\HelloPage.html");
```

Page loads successfully. Now I have a button on webpage and I want to navigate to another page designed using **jquery-mobile** and added to the project resources on this button's click event. I have a button and link on my web page to load another pages as following:

```
<a id="myLink" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-mini" href="Page2.html" >Rollout</a>

<button type="submit" id="submitData" runat="server" onclick="Page3.html;" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-mini">Submit</button>
```

Both the above mentioned events gives me **Error Loading Page**. I tried another technique to call **c#** method from javascript and make a call to load my page inside that method but  couldn't achieve that. Can anybody please help me with this. Its my first project on c#. I want to know where I am doing wrong or what other options do I have to make it work. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

Dude it's miles off.
I suggest try your code in a web page (hosted locally or remotely) that works. The above code:

```
onclick="Page3.html;"
```

Isn't going to work terribly well. Try and refer to a js function in onclick instead, the point is - get a working webpage first - preferably referring to external assets such as a js file and a css stylesheet.

Then you can look at cef packaging. Typically you'll need to set your web assets as embedded resources and access them using

> Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream

but you're a long way from that yet. Concentrate on the webpage first.

Comment: thanks for the response :-). Please check my code snippet attached to the question, I have tried both the **onclick** and **href** techniques and I know it should redirect to the targeted page but in my case it is not.

Comment: Ok lets concentrate on the anchor tag. It's much simpler as it's a simple URL.
Have you tried .\Page2.html ?? Also add handlers - the easiest by far is to register a scheme, 'bg' say:

CefSharp.CEF.RegisterScheme("bl", new BgSchemeFactory());

Then you can change the href in your anchor to 'bg://Page2.html'.
Your schemeFactory should now return the new html.

I hope that helps. If not DO checkout bunglaow - http://code.google.com/p/bungalow/

Comment: I got it. My page was not loading because the way i loaded my home page into browser. I was using **LoadHtml()** instead of **load()**. Once I changed it to the later it is working perfectly. thanks for consideration :-)

Answer (score 0):

change this;

```
<button type="submit" id="submitData" runat="server" onclick="window.location.href='Page3.html';" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-mini">Submit</button>
```